# GStreamer 1.0 encode raw to H.264 in C

Tags: c, h.264, gstreamer-1.0

I am working with GStreamer-1.0 **version: 1.10.4**

I have a raw video file which I want to encode with h.264 using GStreamer in C.

My Pipeline looks as follows:

**gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=myVideo.yuv blocksize=2073600 ! videoparse width=1920 height=1080 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! queue ! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=myFile.mp4**

This pipeline works fine when I execute it in the terminal. But I want to do it with the C-API so my source code looks as follows:

```
GstElement* pipeline;

GstElement* src;
GstElement* videoparse;
GstElement* decodebin;
GstElement* videoconvert;
GstElement* x264enc;
GstElement* queue;
GstElement* mp4mux;
GstElement* filesink;

pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

src = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", NULL);
if(!src) {
    GST_WARNING("Error in: src");
}

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(src),"location","myVideo.yuv",NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(src),2073600,NULL);

videoparse = gst_element_factory_make("videoparse", NULL);
if(!videoparse) {
    GST_WARNING("Error in: videoparse");
}

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(videoparse),"width",1920,NULL);
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(videoparse),"height",1080,NULL);

decodebin = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", NULL);
if(!decodebin) {
    GST_WARNING("Error in: decodebin");
}

videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", NULL);
if(!videoconvert) {
    GST_WARNING("Error in: videoconvert");
}   

x264enc = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", NULL);
if(!x264enc) {
    GST_WARNING("Error in: x264enc");
}    

queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", NULL);
if(!queue) {
    GST_WARNING("Error in: queue");
}     

mp4mux = gst_element_factory_make("mp4mux", NULL);
if(!mp4mux) {
    GST_WARNING("Error in: mp4mux");
}     

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(mp4mux),"name","mux",NULL);

filesink = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", NULL);
if(!filesink) {
    GST_WARNING("Error in: filesink");
}     

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesink),"location","myFile.mp4",NULL);

gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline),src,videoparse,decodebin,videoconvert,x264enc,queue,mp4mux,filesink, NULL);

gst_element_link(src, videoparse);
gst_element_link(videoparse, decodebin);
gst_element_link(decodebin, videoconvert);
gst_element_link(videoconvert, x264enc);
gst_element_link(x264enc, queue);
gst_element_link(queue, mp4mux);
gst_element_link(mp4mux, filesink);

gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

sleep(40);
```

As I said the pipeline in the terminal works fine, but the C implementation only creates an empty mp4 file. And I don't understand why.

In case it might be helpful: The recording of the raw videofile has also been done with GStreamer. The pipeline used for this is:

**gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=300 ! queue ! image/jpeg,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! jpegdec ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! filesink location=myVideo.yuv**

I would like to know if anybody can see a mistake I made or if somebody faced similar issues.

Comment: g_object_set(G_OBJECT(src),"location",myVideo.yuv,NULL);
Can you explain me what is the value of myVideo.yuv?
It should be string.

Comment: Sorry, this was a mistake from my side. I replaced all variables by static names and numbers in order to keep it readable for the forum.

At this point I should also mention that gst_init(NULL,NULL); is also already called.

Anyway, this is not the problem. I found out that **videoparse** seems to be the troublemaker. I tried to replace it by **rawvideoparse** but without success. I have no idea what could be wrong with my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the return values of any functions. Linking elements can fail for example, or setting the state.

In your case the problem is a) linking decodebin to videoconvert (it has sometimes pads, you need to connect to the "pad-added" signal and link from there, check the GStreamer docs), b) linking the queue to mp4mux (it has request pads, you have to use gst_element_get_request_pad() to get the correct pad).

Alternatively you could use gst_parse_launch() from C and pass in your pipeline string. It will give you a pipeline that is equivalent to the one created by the gst-launch-1.0 tool, and it will do the two things I mentioned above internally without you having to worry about that.